# .htaccess redirect only URL which begin by a certain text and end with a slash

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I would like to redirect all URL like this:

http://myserver.com/downloads/**toto/titi/** to http://myserver.com/downloads/index.html?dir=**toto/titi/**

- I want to redirect only if the URL begin by **downloads** and **end with a slash** (folders)

But if the adress do not end with a slash '/' I don't want my redirection to works (to be able to downloads files).
So if I have this:
http://myserver.com/downloads/**toto/titi** I want apache to try to open the file titi in folder toto.

Here is my Regex which do not work:

```
    RewriteRule ^downloads/(.+)/$   /downloads/index.html?dir=$1    [L]
```

(As you can see I try to catch anything between downloads/ and the last slash but unfortunately it don't works. The closer I get was a redirection anytime (with or without the last slash) which I don't want too.

It was something like:

```
    RewriteRule ^downloads/(.+)[/]{1}$ downloads/index.html?dir=$1/ [L]
```

The reason of this redirection is that I want to manage the files on my server via a web view. I want to be able to navigate through the folder and download the files I want (by clicking on it and let the browser download it). I want the address to do the same as Dropbox do in is web view. You can navigate throught your folders and there is not a index.html in each folders, of course.

Do you know what my regex should look like ?

Comment: Is the RewriteEngine turned on?

Comment: Yes, the redirection actually works when I put:
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://google.com [L]

Comment: What error do you get and where is this .htaccess located?

Comment: I actually have no errors (I don't know where are the errors for .htaccess fail or redirection).
The .htaccess is located at the root (/var/www) and as I said it works pretty well for my other URL rewritting
It seems like the slashes are distinguished (maybe ignored) by RewriteRule , maybe because they are url components ?